# How to set syntax highlighting in sublime text through editorconfig

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor, editorconfig

my `.editorconfig` file look like this

```
root = true

[*.rush]
syntax = ruby
```

I have put it in the top of the folder hierarchy. However, the sublime text shows all the `.rush` files as plain text and I have to manually change the syntax highlight to Ruby.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax highlighting isn't supported by EditorConfig yet.

The core set of supported properties that is widely supported by all editors -

- `indent_style`
- `indent_size`
- `tab_width`
- `end_of_line`
- `charset`
- `trim_trailing_whitespace`
- `insert_final_newline`
- `root`

`max_line_length` is supported by a limited number of editors (*Emacs, Vim, Atom, ReSharper, Rider, AppCode, IntelliJ IDEA, PhpStorm, PyCharm, RubyMine, and WebStorm*)

It's still an open issue ([#190](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/190)) to support highlighting.

You can find other proposed properties on its [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#propose-new-properties-and-values).

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to be able to specify the syntax in the `.editorconfig` file.

Alternatively, it could be a new standard that editors or programs can look at for specifying the syntax of different globs, file names, or file extensions.

`[$]> cat ~/.syntaxconfig`

`[$]> cat ~/.syntaxmapping`

```ini
[.custom_shell] bash
[{*.rush, *.wish}] ruby
```

```ini
bash [.custom_shell]
ruby [{*.rush, *.wish}]
```

```ini
[bash]
.custom_shell

[ruby]
*.rush
*.wish
```